# Can't find books in Careers UI

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, jobs

I'm trying to list a couple of books I've read, all of my searches are coming up blank.

I started out trying to list [ASP.NET MVC Framework Preview](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1430216468)
Here's the ISBN I tried entering

> 1430216468

I also tried entering

> ASP.NET MVC

Both returned no results.

Is this bit broken?

Comment: It seems broken, to me. I have tried using the 13-digit code, but it didn't work. I have also tried with the ISBN code for a book I have already added to my profile, but not even that worked; I don't get any result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was broken – Amazon changed their API responses slightly and caught us off guard. Would you try it again?